# How to find the segment corresponding to an address in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

Here is a snippet:

```
char * cptr3 = "Hello"; // Line 1
char c = *(cptr3+3);    // Line 2
*(cptr3+3)= '7';        // Line 3 : will result in AV
```

How can i find that the cptr3 lies in read only data segment or code(text) segment?
I would prefer VS2010 as i use windows but I am open to other alternatives as well.

Comment: Pro tip: write your code so that this issue never arises.  (For example, use a `const char *` here.)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It could also live in the stack, depending on the context.

Comment: I know that it should be const char* i did this intentionally to see why this happens that this line 3 results into access violation.point of emphasis here is dt i wanted to know dt what wud be the difference between storage of declarations made here...

Comment: @cup : Stack is not something i was expecting :-)
However, is there any platform/compiler where it will go to stack? I DON'T THINK SO as "This is a string constant". If compiler puts string constant then wouldn't compiler be doing something wrong?

Comment: Is your question about what cptr3 points to or where it lives?  What cptr3 points to ("Hello") may live anywhere.  If declared in a routine, cptr3 lives on the stack.  If declared globally, cptr3 will live in data.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i find that the cptr3 lies in read only data segment or code(text) segment?

From the C language perspective you can't.

There might by possibilities using the one or the other C implemementation, but those are not portable.